# Lint infrastructure error Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException - Android Studio 4.2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, lint

Every time I change the code or change the layout file I get the below error :

Execution failed for task ':app:lint'.

> Lint infrastructure error
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.api.ReflectiveLintRunner.runLint(ReflectiveLintRunner.kt:37)
> at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintBaseTask.runLint(LintBaseTask.java:133)
> at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.LintGlobalTask.doTaskAction(LintGlobalTask.java:37)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalGlobalTask$taskAction$$inlined$recordTaskAction$1.invoke(BaseTask.kt:63)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Blocks.recordSpan(Blocks.java:51)
> at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.NonIncrementalGlobalTask.taskAction(NonIncrementalTask.kt:90)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:58)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:51)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:29)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:555)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:540)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:523)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:108)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:271)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:260)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:34)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:34)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:67)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:42)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:159)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:72)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:43)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:265)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
> at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
> at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:187)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:179)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
> at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
> at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor.process(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:72)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.executeWithServices(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:184)
> at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:177)
> at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:39)
> at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.java:40)
> at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.access$000(DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.java:24)
> at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildWorkExecutor$1.proceed(DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.java:48)
> at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:49)
> at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.java:40)
> at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildWorkExecutor.java:33)
> at org.gradle.execution.IncludedBuildLifecycleBuildWorkExecutor.execute(IncludedBuildLifecycleBuildWorkExecutor.java:36)
> at org.gradle.execution.DeprecateUndefinedBuildWorkExecutor.execute(DeprecateUndefinedBuildWorkExecutor.java:42)
> at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor$ExecuteTasks.run(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:57)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
> at org.gradle.execution.BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.execute(BuildOperationFiringBuildWorkerExecutor.java:42)
> at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runWork(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:265)
> at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doClassicBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:174)
> at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
> at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:126)
> at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:72)
> at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)
> at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:178)
> at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
> at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:54)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:67)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
> at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
> at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:87)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
> at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:49)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
> at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
> at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
> at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
> at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
> at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at com.intellij.openapi.util.KeyedExtensionCollector.getPoint(KeyedExtensionCollector.java:203)
> at com.intellij.openapi.util.KeyedExtensionCollector.getExtensions(KeyedExtensionCollector.java:135)
> at com.intellij.openapi.util.KeyedExtensionCollector.buildExtensions(KeyedExtensionCollector.java:124)
> at com.intellij.openapi.util.KeyedExtensionCollector.forKey(KeyedExtensionCollector.java:109)
> at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.impl.VirtualFileManagerImpl.getFileSystem(VirtualFileManagerImpl.java:107)
> at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.StandardFileSystems$1.compute(StandardFileSystems.java:24)
> at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.StandardFileSystems$1.compute(StandardFileSystems.java:20)
> at com.intellij.openapi.util.ClearableLazyValue.getValue(ClearableLazyValue.java:39)
> at com.intellij.openapi.vfs.StandardFileSystems.local(StandardFileSystems.java:40)
> at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.readFile(LintCliClient.kt:547)
> at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient$getSourceText$1.apply(LintCliClient.kt:479)
> at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient$getSourceText$1.apply(LintCliClient.kt:116)
> at java.base/java.util.HashMap.computeIfAbsent(HashMap.java:1133)
> at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.getSourceText(LintCliClient.kt:479)
> at com.android.tools.lint.HtmlReporter$writeIssueCard$1.invoke(HtmlReporter.kt:259)
> at com.android.tools.lint.HtmlReporter$writeIssueCard$1.invoke(HtmlReporter.kt:56)
> at com.android.tools.lint.HtmlReporter.writeCard(HtmlReporter.kt:764)
> at com.android.tools.lint.HtmlReporter.writeIssueCard(HtmlReporter.kt:175)
> at com.android.tools.lint.HtmlReporter.write(HtmlReporter.kt:120)
> at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.lintAllVariants(LintGradleExecution.kt:428)
> at com.android.tools.lint.gradle.LintGradleExecution.analyze(LintGradleExecution.kt:74)
> ... 216 more

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

I already have this in my app gradle :

```
   lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
```

and even on doing the **Project clean** from the menu , on rebuilding it again throws this error.
only way to get out of this error is to delete the app/build and Project/build file.

any simple fix for this?

I am on Android Studio 4.2.2

and below is my app gradle settings :

```
 compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "31.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.getangle"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
```

Comment: Any solution @Raulp?

Comment: nothing but this : only way to get out of this error is to delete the app/build and Project/build file.

Answer (score 3):

```
android {
    ...
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `abortOnError true`. It should ignor lint error. Lint is a tool that checks for warnings and errors on your project. And additionally I advise you to use [Android Studio Canary](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview?gclid=CjwKCAiAwKyNBhBfEiwA_mrUMgDipky7Vm34qh3Gt-QCjl0kQIr1sMYhKSx6IbN-HlPCJOS6LN58bRoC74cQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) version.